# Find function within a Do Loop providing inconsistent results

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to test the differences between two lists. My VBA code is supposed to loop through list one and use the find method to look at each item in list two. If the item is not found in list two, I use the copy , paste method to log it in my compare sheet. The code then goes back and does the reverse procedure to test list two on list one; loop through list two and look for each item in list 1.

My Results imply and inconsistent number of matching results. The number of items in list 1 minus the results from the "list1" find loop do not equal number of items in list two minus the number of items from "list2' find loop. The remaining items should only be values that where found in each list.

All items are primary keys and are unique within their respective list.

```
Public Sub compare_list()
Dim wsList2 As Worksheet
Dim wsList1 As Worksheet
Dim wsCompare As Worksheet
Dim found1 As Range

Set wsList2 = Worksheets("List2")
Set wsList1 = Worksheets("List1")
Set wsCompare = Worksheets("Compare")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Check each value in client_id list one with list two
wsList1.Activate
wsList1.Range("a1").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

Set found1 = wsList2.Range("a1",_
wsList2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Find(Selection.Value)
    If found1 Is Nothing Then
    Selection.Copy
    wsCompare.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

'Check each value in client_id list two with list one
wsList2.Activate
wsList2.Range("a1").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

Set found1 = wsList1.Range("a1",_
wsList1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Find(Selection.Value)
        If found1 Is Nothing Then
        Selection.Copy
        wsCompare.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
Loop

wsCompare.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Just a note: I am very new to VBA, and do not come from a developer back ground. You probably can't dumb down your solution too much.

Comment: Is a Non-VBA solution an option? If so ... [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) where the formulas compare the lists against each other?  If not, have you stepped through your code, line-by-line, to see where it is not acting the way you want it to? If not, do that, and I bet you can find your problem, or at least update your post with a more specific and directed question.

Comment: I tried your code with a view lines per sheet. The result seems to be ok from my point of view. The way of implementation can be improved of course but in general it should work. Are you sure that your lists do not contain any duplicates? Because the code would of course not check if a entry is twice in list 1 but only once in list 2 (in this case it will not be shown as missing in the result). This would explain the not matching numbers

Comment: You're using the same worksheet in both `Set found1 = wsList2.Range("a1", ...` lines.  Shouldn't one of them be `wsList1.` and the other `wsList2`?

Comment: BruceWayne that is a typo in preparing the code copy for this site teh second find loop should refer to wslist1

Comment: Can you update your post then according to @BruceWayne? Also, can you edit with sample lists data and add how code currently results and your desired results?

Comment: cboden - I have gone back and verified that all client_ids in a list are unique within their list.

Comment: @Parfait it is a large set of rows so I'll see what i can do about a sample set. But to clarify a little on my expectation vs the actual results. List one has 10077 rows, 285 items in that list result in the find method returning nothing, Implying that list 1 has 9792 items in come with list 2. But List 2 has a total of 9955 rows and 154 items from the find method return nothing. Implying that List 2 has 9801 items in common with list 1. I would expect those the number of items in common should be the same.

Comment: Just checked your code. I put in `List1` wks in Col A, numbers 1-33, 121-126; and in `List2` wks, in Col A: numbers 1-120. In `Compare` wks, it outputted in Col A: 121-126 and Col B: 34-120. So `Compare` outputs all that is **not** in either List. As shown, number of items between lists do not have to be in common. Lists may skip values. It depends on where they derive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a default parameter in the find function. I needed to set the `LookAt:=xlWhole`

For example, list 1 = (1,2,32,142) and list 2 = (1,2,3,132)

For my purposes 32 is not in list 2 but without setting that parameter the find function returns a result when search for 32 as it finds it in the cell containing 132

The following is the code that is working for me now. Thanks for all your help

```
Public Sub compare_list()
Dim wsList2 As Worksheet
Dim wsList1 As Worksheet
Dim wsCompare As Worksheet
Dim found1 As Range
Dim found2 As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim countList2 As Integer
Dim countList1 As Integer
Dim listDiff As Integer
Dim commonList2 As Integer
Dim commonList1 As Integer
Dim diffList1 As Integer
Dim diffList2 As Integer


Set wsList2 = Worksheets("List2")
Set wsList1 = Worksheets("List1")
Set wsCompare = Worksheets("Compare")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


'Check each value in the client_id list created by List1 to find an equal     value in List2's list

Set myCell = wsList1.Range("A1")

Do Until myCell.Value = ""

Set found1 = wsList2.Range("a1",   wsList2.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=myCell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If found1 Is Nothing Then
    myCell.Copy
    wsCompare.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Else
    myCell.Copy
    wsCompare.Range("G1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If

Set myCell = myCell.Offset(1, 0)

Loop

'Check each value in the client_id list created by List2 to find an equesl value in List1's list

Set myCell = wsList2.Range("A1")

Do Until myCell.Value = ""

Set found2 = wsList1.Range("a1",  wsList1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=myCell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If found2 Is Nothing Then
    myCell.Copy
    wsCompare.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    Else
    myCell.Copy
    wsCompare.Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If

Set myCell = myCell.Offset(1, 0)

 Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 wsCompare.Activate

'test logic of result
countList1 = wsList1.Range("a2", wsList1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Rows.count
countList2 = wsList2.Range("a2", wsList2.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp)).Rows.count


diffList1 = (wsCompare.Range("a2",   wsCompare.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Rows.count - 1)
diffList2 = (wsCompare.Range("b2",     wsCompare.Range("b1048576").End(xlUp)).Rows.count - 1)

listDiff = Abs(countList1 - countList2)

commonList2 = (countList2 - diffList2)
commonList1 = (countList1 - diffList1)

MsgBox "List2 has " & commonList2 & " in common with List1" & vbCrLf & "List1     has " & commonList1 & " in common with List2"


End Sub
```